# Could not activate the pcap handler

Tags: python, linux, wifi

I try to sniff network adapter(TP-LINK, 0bda:b711) with python3 , But I get an OSError: Could not activate the pcap handler

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.config import conf
from scapy.layers.dot11 import Dot11


conf.use_pcap = True


def callBack(pkg):
    if pkg.haslayer(Dot11):
        if pkg.type == 0 and pkg.subtype == 8:
            print("dBm_AntSignal=", pkg.dBm_AntSignal)
            print("dBm_AntNoise=", pkg.dBm_AntNoise)


sniff(iface='wlp1s1', monitor='True', prn=callBack)
```

I think there is something wrong with libpcap, I want to get dBm_AntSignal and dBm_AntNoise from sniff, the code can run Macbook according to other people(you can browse my last question). Is there somebody can solve this issue ?

Comment: do you have the privileges necessary to sniff on that device?

Comment: yes, I use sudo to run python file

Answer (score 0):

If you posted [issue #1136 on the libpcap issues list](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/issues/1136), then you presumably somehow managed to determine that `pcap_activate()` returned `PCAP_ERROR`.  If you did that by modifying the Scapy code, try modifying it further to, if `pcap_activate()` returns `PCAP_ERROR`, report the result of `pcap_geterr()`, in order to try to find out *why*, in this particular instance, `pcap_activate()` returned `PCAP_ERROR`.  The problem is that `PCAP_ERROR` can be returned for a number of different reasons, and it's difficult if not impossible to guess which one it was.

(And then file an issue on [Scapy's issue list](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues) indicating that the error message for `pcap_activate()` failing should be based on both the return value from `pcap_activate()` and, for certain errors, the result of `pcap_geterr()`.  They should also distinguish between error returns from `pcap_activate()`, which are negative numbers, and *warning* returns from `pcap_activate()`, which indicate that the "pcap handler" *could* be activated, but something unexpected happened, and are *positive* numbers.)

Update:

No need to file the Scapy issue; I've already submitted [a pull request for the change to fix the error reporting](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/3796), and it's been merged.  Apply [the changes from that pull request](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/3796/files) to Scapy and try again.